# Accesing vector elements one by one opencl

Tags: vector, opencl

I need to add sum of two float in vector type in for loop in opencl

```
     float16 temp;
     for( int j = 0; j <16; j++)
     {
        float sum = row * column;   // Row x column
    
         temp = sum;            
     }
```

I need output something like temp = sum0, sum1.....

Answer (score 0):

Here regular `float` is the way to go. While you can address the components of `float16` individually with `.s0`, `.s1`, ..., `.sf`, you can not automate this in a loop with a loop index (see the [OpenCL 1.2 Reference Guide](https://www.khronos.org/files/opencl-1-2-quick-reference-card.pdf)). The only way with `float16` would be to manually write it down for every loop iteration, which is not practical.

However with `float temp[16];` you can do exactly that. Your code then would look like this:

```c
float temp[16];
for(int j=0; j<16; j++) {
    float sum = row * column; // Row x column
    temp[j] = sum;
}
```

To convert `temp` into `float16`, you would have to do it manually for every component, which again is tedious:

```c
float16 temp2 = (float16)(temp[0], temp[1], ..., temp[16]);
```

I would advise you to get rid of `float16` entirely in your particular application. Using regular `float*` arrays is more practical (automatic indexing in loops) and also faster when you access the data from global memory: You can use Structure-of-Arrays and are not bound to the much slower Array-of-Structures data layout.